# Objective C strange decimal to long long conversion

Tags: objective-c, decimal, long-integer

```
NSLog(@"%llu\n\n", ULONG_LONG_MAX);

NSDecimalNumber *decimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"154550038129946620"];
NSLog(@"%@", decimal);
NSLog(@"%llu\n\n", [decimal unsignedLongLongValue]);

decimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"154550038129946628"];
NSLog(@"%@", decimal);
NSLog(@"%llu", [decimal unsignedLongLongValue]);
```

Both value are less than ULONG_LONG_MAX. But, what we see in output is:

```
2012-01-05 17:41:55.879 test[1276:207] 18446744073709551615

2012-01-05 17:41:55.969 test[1276:207] 154550038129946620
2012-01-05 17:41:56.095 test[1276:207] 154550038129946624

2012-01-05 17:41:56.096 test[1276:207] 154550038129946628
2012-01-05 17:41:56.096 test[1276:207] 154550038129946624
```

What am I doing wrong? I have no idea how to explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber` lacks the `unsignedLongLongValue` method, so it inherits a default implementation from `NSNumber`. The only ways to get value of `NSDecimalNumber` are getting an `NSDecimal` structure, or a `double`. The conversion error is introduced in the process of converting `NSDecimalNumber` to a `double`.

Comment: I didn't get it from the beginning and posted my own answer, but now I get it, and your answer is equal to mine. For others, who, just like me, didn't completely understand - the decimal inside `NSDecimalNumber` is casted to double before casting to unsigned long long. Anyway, I think that's fundamental SDK bug.

Comment: @AlexanderN. I disagree that this is a fundamental SDK shortcoming: if you stay within `NSDecimalNumber`s, you get solid precision, which is all that matters to the designers of the SDK. Conversions to other types are there for mere convenience; their use comes with understanding that some precision may be lost due to differences in representation.

Comment: I undestand it. But don't you think it's a little weird - cast integer (in this case) decimal to integer long long and lose precision, like in float-int casting?

Comment: @AlexanderN. I agree that this is a shortcoming in the design: architects of the `NSDecimalNumber` could have provided a more intuitive behavior, especially since the architecture provides everything they need to make it right. All they needed was to override a method that is already there for them. But it is not large enough to call it fundamental.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right, and I just got too excited about this issue :) Well, at least it's odd enough to keep it in mind while dealing with decimals.